# submit input text to shuffle image array

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, text, input

I can't get this text input to *properly* activate the random shuffle image array. It will activate it, but on initial click. I would like it to require validation from the user inputting and then submitting text.

```js
<style>iframe {display:none !important;}
    <!--
p {color:#000000; font-size:14px; font-family: verdana,  serif}
.title {color:#000000; font-size:14px; font-family: verdana,  serif}
-->
iframe:first-child { display: none !important; } {

top: 0% !important;

right:0% !important; 

display:none !important;

}

</style>
<script language="javascript">



var imagesArray = [
'https://assets.entrepreneur.com/content/3x2/1300/20150827173347-test-google-adwords-campaign-search-engine-internet.jpeg',
'https://yt3.ggpht.com/-DvvzUuiYGos/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/YoUb-VzIovA/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg',
'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/tu-bav-2015-5651988540817408-hp2x.jpg',
'https://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/splashes/featured.png',
'http://www.onetechstop.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/google-logo.jpg',
];

var usedImages = {};
var usedImagesCount = 0;

function displayImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
    if ($('#textbox').val() === '') {
    e.preventDefault();
}
    if (!usedImages[num]){
        document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
        usedImages[num] = true;
        usedImagesCount++;
        if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
            usedImagesCount = 0;
            usedImages = {};
        }
    } else {
        displayImage();
    }
}




</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeOut()
    });
});

    

</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
<center>
<form name="imageForm">

   <tr align="center">
   <td><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8bp6n2l.jpg" name="canvas" /><br><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
<center>
        <input  type="text"  class="btn1" id = "textbox"  size="60" ><br><br>
      <input onclick="displayImage();" type="reset"  value="Submit" class="btn1" /><br/>

    </td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
</form>
<p><b>Progress</b> or <b>React?</b></p>

</head>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<center>
<form name="imageForm">

   <tr align="center">
   <td><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8bp6n2l.jpg" name="canvas" /><br><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
<center>
        <input  onclick="displayImage();" type="text"  class="btn1" id = "textbox"  size="60" ><br><br>
      <br/>

    </td>
  </tr>

  </table>
</form>

</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you neg me? I thought I made this as easy/clear as possible :(

Comment: Probably unrelated to the neg, but I think it would be nice if you could make a snippet of your problem. Click the last button in the second column `[<>]`. Also, have you looked at using `confirm`?

Comment: @A.Lau awesome, I think I may have done that... let me know how I can help you help me, hah!

Comment: Ah ignore the confirm, didn't see you had an input text, just saw the submit button. And I don't think you quite understand how the snippets work, so maybe just use jsfiddle for now :) And I think just adding a `return` inside `if ($('#textbox').val() === '')` should be enough (if you just want to check if it's empty or not.

Comment: @A.Lau hmm, the `return` isn't doing anything, it seems, but neither is the rest of my code in jsfiddle... but even in my typical editor, which renders what I've done, the `return` doesn't do anything unfortunately https://jsfiddle.net/g0su9dpq/1/#&togetherjs=8OUz6DgCHd

Comment: You really need to try running your stuff first before just copying and pasting the content into jsfiddle/snippets, as they have already inbuilt html and bodies. You're also putting the javascript and html in the wrong places (you don't need script or style tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of unclosed tags in your provided snippet and such. But adding the `return` inside the if statement prevents the image from changing if there's no input.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tv6rL23x/3/

```
if ($('#textbox').val() === '') 
{
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you have truly been **sooo** accommodating, but unfortunately I'm still where I started off, with a non-responsive input form that only refreshes the page, and won't activate my image array script. I'm wandering how to link the `submission` of any `text input` to the `Image Array`'s random shuffle command, the way the `submit button` does so well now, so that the presence of `text` in the `input` field is **required to validate** the `submission` to the `image array` script.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. An empty text field won't change the image, while any input will allow the image to change. What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Because from what I can tell, it's doing what you're describing. What's trying to validate what?

Comment: The main problem is the continually refreshing `input form`. When input "on its own," with an exterior **enter key** and without the `submit button,` irregarless of text input, it will just refresh the page :(. Ideally, the user _should_ be able to **press enter** without the `submit button` and, if text is input, change the image, no page refresh. With no text input, it should just stay totally static, the way the submit button does now, no refresh. And just like the submit button, when there's text **input** and **submitted,** _button or otherwise,_ the images change

Comment: Wow you're the best! One last tiny thing, can the form reset to blank upon solo input, as it does when assisted by the submit button?

Comment: You'll have to do that manually. Either by just having `$('#textbox').val('')` at the bottom of the function or getting your form and using `reset()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to change on input just add a oninput event listener. However, I advise you not to use inline-event-listeners in this case as there are multiple events you want to listen for.

Perhaps adding the event listener with your `displayImage()` code would be better.

```
...
<center>
        <input  onclick="displayImage()" oninput="displayImage()" type="text"  class="btn1" id = "textbox"  size="60" ><br><br>
      <br/>

    </td>
  </tr>

  </table>
</form>

</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction! I don't want multiple events, onlick or input, but only upon the _submission_ of the essential user text input, by clicking enter or through a submit button, such as...

<input onclick="displayImage();" type="reset"  value="Submit" class="btn1" />

the onclick works with the simple "onclick," especially when I specify with script that the text input is required to validate its submission for the "displayImage()" command. But I wander if this is getting in the way? 

 if ($('#textbox').val() === '') {
    e.preventDefault();
}